# Get facebook public photo from scoped user id

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

FB.api("me", function (response) { }); now returns a 'app_scoped_user_id' instead of the old user id. My app use to get a users profile photo with graph.facebook.com/id/picture but this doesnt work for the scoped id. How do I get this now?

Comment: Why should this not work for the app-scoped user id? In my test it seems to work just fine. So what exactly have you tried?

Comment: my scope id : http://graph.facebook.com/10152708800530701/picture my actual id http://graph.facebook.com/522390700/picture... it dont work

Comment: Both redirect me to the same picture in my browser …

Comment: weird... Yes theres an actual fb bug here. my mobile works, my desktop doesnt!